# Getting first unused number

Tags: vb.net

I want to find the first unused number in listbox, that contains random numbers, but im getting this error. Could you maybe tell me what am i missing here?

'Unable to cast object of type 'ObjectCollection' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'.'

What I have tried:

```
Dim FB As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, Integer.MaxValue).Except(ListBox1.Items).FirstOrDefault()
MessageBox.Show(FB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is as the error message says: you are passing a `ListBox.ObjectCollection` where an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` is expected. `Enumerable.Range` returns an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` so that's the type that `Except` expects as well. It's exactly for such scenarios that the the `Cast(Of T)` method exists. You call it on an `IEnumerable` object to get an `IEnumerable(Of T)` object. Of course, the items in the list have to actually be type `T` to begin with.

```
Dim FB = Enumerable.Range(0, Integer.MaxValue).Except(ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Integer)()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

The items in a ListBox are Objects. Here I converted them back to Integers and the used the .Max method on the resulting enumerable.

```
Dim FB = (From item In ListBox1.Items
          Select CInt(item)).Max
 MessageBox.Show(FB.ToString)
```

If you turn on Option Strict for all your codes some of these errors will be spotted before you try to run your code. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.